# php's if shorthand when there are multiple elseifs

Tags: php

How can I use shorthand for php's if when there are multiple elseifs?

I know how to do it with one condition, but what when there are several?

This is how it is:

```
if($a == 00){ 
 echo 'Clear';
}elseif ($a == 01) {
 echo 'Processing';
} elseif ($a == 10) {
 echo 'Marked for delete';
}
```

Comment: It works. I'm trying to use if's shorthand Eg:`($age > 10 ? ($score < 80 ? 'behind' : 'above average') : ($score < 50 ? 'behind' : 'above average'))`

Comment: If you do it, you'll regret it - nested ternaries ar not intuitive, and can lead to hard debugging problems, and the fact that you'll spend days trying to figure it all out again if you ever need to change it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can of course "chain" the ternary operator, but that results in horrible code. **Don't do it**.

Use an `if`/`else`, a `switch` or possibly an associative array as appropriate. For example, you could do this:

```
$messages = array(
    00 => 'Clear',
    01 => 'Processing',
    10 => 'Marked for delete',
);

echo isset($messages[$a]) ? $messages[$a] : null;
```

In this case this won't be at all better than the `if` or `switch` statements, but it's a useful tool to keep in mind.

Answer (score 5):

The [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement?

```
switch ($a) {
  case 0:
    echo "Clear";
    break;
  case 1:
    echo "Processing";
    break;
  case 2:
    echo "Marked for delete";
    break;
}
```

alternatively you can use the ternary operator:

```
echo ($a == 0 ? "Clear" :
     ($a == 1 ? "Processing" :
     ($a == 2 ? "Marked for delete" : "")));
```

Comment: agreed that it is more readable than most people write it, but if you have a lot of options, you will end up with a string of close brackets at the end, which isn't great. I'd still prefer to use a different syntax to nested ternaries.

Answer (score 2):

use [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

```
switch ($a) {
    case 1:
        echo "clear";
        break;
    case 10:
        echo "marked default";
        break;
    default:
        echo "not tracked case";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should **NEVER** do this, it is utterly unreadable but...

```
echo ($a==00?"Clear":($a== 01?"Processing":($a == 10?"Marked For Delete":"")));
```

Comment: In my opinion it this kinda stuff makes php a write only language

Comment: @slebetman Actually looking at your post it works... never seen it laided out that way.... I like

Comment: The formatting is a bit broken due to PHP's insistence of using ((())). It looks much better in C or javascript.

Comment: @slebetman  but your form I can look at and I know what's going on. personally I would still go with a switch but if one of my coworkers wrote a ternary like that I wouldn't feel compelled to club them over the head

Comment: What I meant was the same form also work in C and javascript - but they look much better than in PHP because C and javascript doesn't force you to use braces () around your ternary operators.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

`echo ($a==0 ? 'clear' : ($a==01 ? 'Processing' : ($a==10 ? 'Marked for delete' : '' )));`

But Jon is right, don't do it - as you can see, the code is ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the switch statement might be better suited for multiple elseif's

```
switch ($a) {
    case "00":
        break;
    case "Clear":
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of ternary operator (shorthand of if/else)

```
$days = ($month == 2 ? ($year % 4 ? 28 : ($year % 100 ? 29 
: ($year %400 ? 28 : 29)))
 : (($month - 1) % 7 % 2 ? 30 : 31)); 
//returns days in the given month
```

But it will be confusing to work!

So i prefer to work with switch case!

```
switch ($type) {
  case 'a':
    $type = 'Type A';
    break;

  case 'b':
    $type = 'Type B';
    break;

  case 'c':
    $type = 'Type C';
    break;

  default:
    break;
}
```